# How to get path of sub directory of a temporary directory in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, temporary-files, dockerpy

I need to pass path of subdirectory of a temporary directory to another function.

**Real scenario:**

User will upload a zip or tar archive then it will be extracted inside a temporary directory, now I need the path of that extracted directory.

is there a way to get path of a subdirectory in case we couldn't known the name of that directory?
Here's what I'm doing in code;

**views.py**

```
            if form.is_valid():
               deployment = TarWithDocker()
               deployment.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
               deployment.user = request.user
               deployment.archive = form.cleaned_data['archive']
               deployment.save()
               tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
               saved_umask = os.umask(0o077)
               path = os.path.join(tmpdir)
               arpath = deployment.archive.path
               patoolib.extract_archive(arpath, outdir=path)
               client = docker.from_env()
               dirp = os.path.join(path)
               client.images.build(path=# Here i need to pass sub path of directory of temp dir   #}
                                , gzip=False, tag='newdep')
               os.umask(saved_umask)
               shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```

Help me, please!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you give example whats path in your code and what you actually want

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are running

```
client = docker.from_env()
client.images.build(...)
```

I will assume that you are expecting a `Dockerfile` in the archive.

So after extracting the data into `tmpdir`, try this:

```
import glob

docker_glob = os.path.join(tmpdir, "*", "Dockerfile")
docker_file = glob.glob(docker_glob)[0]
docker_folder = os.path.dirname(docker_file)
client.images.build(path=docker_folder, ...)
```

Comment: it works for me, I was needed that for two scenerios one with dockerfile but another scenario couldn't have dockerfile, so in that case I have used package.json instead of dockerfile and it works fine! Thanks @Harald

Comment: Now, again it's throwing:  `docker_file = glob.glob(docker_glob)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range` Error!